# How to setup Linux VM in azure so that we can make it as a server(not a apache web server) for socket programming

Tags: python, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I Just install linux VM in azure cloud and created a server.py which basically receive data from client.py located at another host and returns capitalize form of data. When i run server.py in my vm its running and  when i send data through client.py to the server.py i don't know wether the data transaction occurs or no wether connection is etablished or not, but nothing happens:

client.py:

```
enter code here

from socket import *
serverName = '13.91.90.71'
serverPort = 12000  
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
message = input('Enter lowercase sentence:')
clientSocket.sendto(message.encode(),(serverName, serverPort))
modifiedMessage, serverAddress = clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)
print (modifiedMessage.decode())
clientSocket.close()
```

server.py:

```
enter code here

from socket import *
serverPort =12000
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))
print('Ready to listen') 
while 1:
    message,clientAddress = serverSocket.recvfrom(2048)
    modifiedMessage = message.upper()
    print(modifiedMessage)
    serverSocket.sendto(modifiedMessage, clientAddress)
```

Comment: As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, and `import *` is almost always bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue, the problem is that you need to change the bind of the server like this:

```
serverSocket.bind(('0.0.0.0', serverPort))
```

or

```
serverSocket.bind(('vm_private_ip', serverPort))
```

The `vm_private_ip` is the real IP address of the VM. And then you also need to add a rule to the NSG associated with the VM to allow the port 12000.